# backpack-for-laravel Error install backpack for Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-backpack

When i try install and i have this error:

```
# composer require backpack/base
Using version ^0.7.3 for backpack/base
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for backpack/base ^0.7.3 -> satisfiable by backpack/base[0.7.3].
    - backpack/base 0.7.3 requires laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.3.x-dev, v5.3.0, v5.3.0-RC1, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.3, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably running a Laravel 5.2 app. If so, you have two options:

1) [Upgrade from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0), then try again, it will most definitely work. The Laravel upgrade takes about about 1 hour for a medium-sized project, but you'll have all the benefits of using the latest and greatest (both Laravel and Backpack).

2) [Install Backpack for Laravel 5.2](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/installation), but please be aware you're running an old Backpack version and you won't be receiving any updates or new features.

My recommendation, of course, is option #1. In the end, you'll still need to update Laravel, then update Backpack, so it's best to just do it now.